# Any recommendation of RAM and CPU usage on android device

Tags: android, debugging

I have a device is showing a slow response and slugginese. Could you please point me to a correct app for monitor a CPU and RAM usage to identify the process that cause this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does anyone know how to use systrace - which is come with Jelly Bean SDK ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Little eye](http://www.littleeye.co/). It is a great tool for profiling Android apps.